# How to display "name" instead of "numbers" for citation?

Tags: citing, natbib

How can i cite name? latex is always displaying numbers such as [1]. but i want specific sentence for example [Thomas, 1980].

After a lot of failed try, I finally found a post here that is related to my problem. but that also didnt help me. so i am wrtting this with some of the command of my latex document.
Here is how my latex looks like.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4 paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{natbib}
\title{this is example}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \twocolumn[
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        here is abstract.
        \noindent
        \textbf{Keywords:} classics. 
        \end{abstract}
        ]
    \section{Conclusion}
       Here is the citation \cite{Thomas}. 
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliography{my bib file}
    \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\end{document}
```

What are the commands that I have to write here so that I get output as "Here is the citation Thomas" ? Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe, just change the style of the citation you use.

Comment: @enthu - The `abbrvnat` bib style is perfectly compatible with creating authoryear-style citation call-outs. What's needed is providing the option `authoryear` to the `natbib` citation management package.

Comment: ***+1*** Thanks @mico, I read your answer below and it perfectly advises on the options and solution (the same as all your great solutions). :)

Answer (score 6):

Since you load the [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) citation management package, all you need to do in order to obtain the desired citation call-out style is to specify the option `authoryear` when loading `natbib`. (If, in addition, you want to use round paretheses instead of square brackets, just add the option `round`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
%% create a small bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybibfile.bib}
@misc{ Thompson , 
    author= "John Thompson", 
    title = "Thoughts", 
    year  = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
%\usepackage{times} % 'times' package is obsolete
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % load these packages *after* amsmath

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} % <-- new: 'authoryear' option
% 'abbrvnat' bib style can produce both authoryear=style 
%   and numeric-style citation call-outs
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} 

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{Thompson}, \citep{Thompson}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.

Comment: Could you please look at my new question? you seem to be knowledgeable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `plainnat` to obtain the style you want (alternatively, have a look at the comment by Mico. You can keep `abbrvnat` if you specify the `authoryear` option to `natbib`).

Try:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
   @book{Gnus,
    author = {David A. Zooll},
    title = {Gnats of the world},
    publisher = {Epic},
    Year = {2018},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
The first citation \citet{Gnus} and some text.
Here is a parenthetic citation \citep{Gnus}.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid your answer is a bit misleading as it seems to suggest that switching bibliography styles from `abbrvnat` to `plainnat` is *necessary* in order to achieve the OP's objective. That's false, though: The `natbib` citation management is capable of producing both numeric-style and authoryear-style citation callouts using both the `plainnat` and the `abbrvnat` bib styles. What's *sufficient* is to load the `natbib` package with an explicit option: either `authoryear` -- to create authoryear-style citation call-outs -- or `numbers` -- to create numeric-style citation call-outs. Please fix.

Comment: @Mico You are right. I was just suggesting a solution giving the desired result.